# bibliography leveled down to subsection

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, bibliographies, sectioning

I used the option

`bibliography=leveldown` in my `scrbook` documentclass to make a bibliography at the end of each section. I am using biblatex. Can I leveldown it by two levels instead? In other words can I have my bibliography as a subsection?

I tried `heading=subbibliography` but does not seem to do it, and it changes the title from "bibliography" to "bibliographic recerences"

In addition, the `section` Bibliography that I get with leveldown does not show up in the `toc` along with the other sections and subsections. How can I have it in the `toc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither KOMA-Script nor `biblatex` have a ready-made option to move the bibliography two levels down, so you will have to manually redefine the heading. (Generally, there are easy-to-use options for common tasks. For less common requests you may have to use other interfaces.)

Assuming this is going to be the standard heading in your document, redefine the `bibliography` heading with `\defbibheading`. You presumably want an unnumbered subsection (`\subsection*`). If you want an entry in the ToC, add `\addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}`.

```
\documentclass[british]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section One}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC of the document: The bibliography is listed as an unnumbered subsection.]

---

If you want to use `leveldown` you can combine that option with `totoc` to obtain a ToC entry for the bibliography at section level.

```
\documentclass[british, bibliography=leveldown, bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section One}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC of document with unnumbered bibliography at section level.]